# In Palantir Foundry, how can I only run tests on some branches of my Python Transform?

Tags: pytest, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

My tests currently run as part of Checks on every Commit, but they take a while to run. Is there a way I can only run the tests on certain branches (e.g., a staging branch)?

Comment: It is possible to parallelise tests, which might improve performance: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/unit-tests/#parallelizing-tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PySpark tests in Foundry run using [PyTest](https://pytest.org). As a result, you can use PyTest's built-in functionality to control whether a test should run or be skipped.

In Foundry, you can see which branch your code is running on in Checks using the `JEMMA_BRANCH` environment variable (n.b.: this variable won't be set during a Build, only in checks).

Combining this with PyTest's [skipif](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=skipif#pytest-mark-skipif) mark, you can configure your tests to only run on particular branches as follows:

```py
import os
import pytest


def only_run_on_branches(run_branches):
    current_branch = os.environ.get('JEMMA_BRANCH')

    return pytest.mark.skipif(
        current_branch not in run_branches and current_branch is not None,
        reason=f"Not running test on current branch ('{current_branch}')"
    )


@only_run_on_branches(["master"])
def test_increment():
    assert "testing" == "hard"
```

You can find more documentation on testing PySpark in Foundry [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/unit-tests/#writing-a-test), and on skipping tests in PyTest [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/skipping.html). That page also shows you how you can skip entire files or directories based on arbitrary logic, too.

Comment: Is JEMMA_BRANCH documented anywhere? Is it supported?